# HTML5 input field with decimal keyboard

Tags: html, mobile

Problem:

1. I need a number keyboard on input field on first load.
2. '##.##" and '##,##'(french decimal format) are both acceptable.

I've tried:

```
<input type= "text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

but only show integer keyboard.

I've also tried:

```
<input type= "number" />
```

but only accepts `'##.##'`, not french format.

Any suggestions on how to bake a field accept the formats I want?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I'd guess that `[0-9.,]*` might work. Basically I'm just including the decimal point characters as options for the regular expression for the field.

Comment: @zzzzBov: That would match: `.8,55.,15` though :-P

Comment: Thanks for feedback, This will bring full keyboard. Is there way to just bring number pad with decimal symbol('.' or ',')

Comment: Just try a better regex maybe: `\d+[,.]?\d*`?

Comment: Any regrex will bring full keyboard except '[0-9]*'. I want number pad with decimal symbols.

Comment: @user2494495: Huh?  What's a regex have to do with the keyboard?  EDIT: OH!  You want the phone to bring up just the number pad!

Comment: Can you use a JavaScript based form validation?  That'd let you use `<input type="number" />` and make sure it matches `\d+[,.]?\d*` (or similar).

Comment: Thanks again about the feedback. type = "Number" would't accept ##,## as french decimal input.